# How to call, invoke or test a Web Service that has Wssp Policy attached?

Tags: web-services, security, soap

I'm unable to test a web service that has a Security Policy attached. I have been required to develop several Web Services and protect them with simple user and password. *There is no further security requeriments (no encription, no SSL, etc).*

In order to test the security bits, I built a dummy web service with top-down method using **jDeveloper11G**. The simple service works and can be tested vía HTTP analyzer and invoked with SoapUI while running in the integrated **WebLogic** server. The service also works when deployed to a stand alone WebLogic 10.3.6.0 server.

Then I try to attach security policies. I have succesfully attached using two methods:

1) At development time by adding the @Policy annotation
2) After deployment using the WLS console, going to the Web Service Configuration tab, then WS-Policy and attaching a policy and letting the console update the deployment plan as per instructed in [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/webservices/ConfigureWSPolicyFile.html).

(After any of these options the HTTP Analyzer is unable to test the service as it doesn't generate the SOAP stucture form to fill in the parameters, nor it allows to paste the text for a request. The Test applet in the server console can't access the WSDL either, so I'm left with SoapUI only)

I conclude that the attachment is correct because when consulting the WSDL from the server, it has Polici related nodes, where the original I wrote doesn't.

The problem comes when I test with SoapUI 5.0.0.

If I don't add any type of user/password information, the response contains:

```
<env:Fault>
   <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Unknown exception, internal system processing error.</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
```

If I add the following headers:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>usertext</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">passwordtext</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

then the response changes to:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <faultcode>wsse:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error codes: 3001 4001 3201 1008 1028 Error code:3001</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

If I add the security information in the properties of the request without removing the headers I added manually to the request then the response becomes:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <faultcode>wsse:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Error on verifying message against security policy Error code:1025</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The properties I change are: Username, Password, Domain, WSS-Password type (PasswordText), WSS-TimeToLive(50000). The property Authentication Type shows the fixed value "No Authorization" and cannot be changed.

If at this point I remove the manually added header the response becomes the same as the second response I included.

I have tried the following pre defined policies:

- Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.1-UsernameToken-Plain-X509-Basic256.xml
- Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.0-UsernameToken-Plain-X509-Basic256.xml
- Wssp1.2-2007-Https-BasicAuth.xml
- Wssp1.2-2007-Https-UsernameToken-Plain.xml

(The last two produce a different error related to the SSL configuration of the server)

I have also made several searches of wsse:InvalidSecurity, and the related error codes in the fault string, but have obtained no relevant information.

I have read several Oracle Docs (such like E17904_01, E23943_01, E12461_01), but there is no information on what to do after attaching the policies nor I find specific informaion on how to modify the request in order to fulfill the security requirements. Also made several searches for examples or the errors I get in this site and others.

So the question is **What further steps are needed to be able to invoke this web service while protecting it with plain text user and password?**

Secondary question is where do I specify which users can access the service? At the moment I assume that any user in the default realm will have access and so I'm testing with a user for wich I now the password in the default security realm "myrealm".

The wsdl as returned by the server after the policy is attached follows:

```html
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. 
-->
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="asegurado.institution.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" targetNamespace="asegurado.institution.org">
  <wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true" />
  <wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.0-UsernameToken-Plain-X509-Basic256.xml">
    <ns0:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <ns0:InitiatorToken>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <ns0:X509Token ns0:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
              <wsp:Policy>
                <ns0:WssX509V3Token10/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </ns0:X509Token>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </ns0:InitiatorToken>
        <ns0:RecipientToken>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <ns0:X509Token ns0:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
              <wsp:Policy>
                <ns0:WssX509V3Token10/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </ns0:X509Token>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </ns0:RecipientToken>
        <ns0:AlgorithmSuite>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <ns0:Basic256/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </ns0:AlgorithmSuite>
        <ns0:Layout>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <ns0:Lax/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </ns0:Layout>
        <ns0:IncludeTimestamp/>
        <ns0:ProtectTokens/>
        <ns0:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </ns0:AsymmetricBinding>
    <ns0:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <ns0:UsernameToken ns0:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <ns0:WssUsernameToken10/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </ns0:UsernameToken>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </ns0:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
    <ns0:Wss10 xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <ns0:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
        <ns0:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </ns0:Wss10>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="asegurado.institution.org" schemaLocation="http://hn-apli-dev:7001/Asegurado/asegurado?xsd=1" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="intentarRequest">
    <part name="request" type="tns:intentarRequest" />
  </message>
  <message name="intentarResponse">
    <part name="response" type="tns:intentarResponse" />
  </message>
  <portType name="asegurado">
    <operation name="intentar">
      <input message="tns:intentarRequest" />
      <output message="tns:intentarResponse" />
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="aseguradoBinding" type="tns:asegurado">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="intentar">
      <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.0-UsernameToken-Plain-X509-Basic256.xml" />
      <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="asegurado.isntitution.org/intentar" />
      <input>
      <soap:body use="literal" parts="request" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" parts="response" />
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="ServicioAsegurado">
    <port name="asegurado" binding="tns:aseguradoBinding" />
  </service>
</definitions>
```